# Comparing 2 lists in powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm not an powershell expert so have some mercy.
I have a list of email addresses from sql:
`$NotEnroled = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "my-server" -Database "my-db" -Query "select UserName from StudentsToDeleteFromO365"`

I also have a list of all mailboxes from o365 exchange:

`$Mailboxes = get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited | where {($_.UserPrincipalName -match '@students.test.com') -and (($_.ForwardingSmtpAddress -ne $NULL) -or ($_.ForwardingAddress -ne $NULL))} | Select UserPrincipalName`

**I'm having a difficult time trying to only get the list $mailboxes which exists in $NotEnrolled** so i can later on delete the license and delete the o365 account.

Comment: Maybe you only need to output the UPN string rather than a custom object. Try `Select -Expand UserPrincipalName` or use `$mailboxes.userprincipalname` in your comparison

Answer (score 0):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) commented, the code you use for retrieving the `$Mailboxes` variable gets you an array of objects, each having a property 'UserPrincipalName'.

Since you want to compare to another array containing strings, this will not work.

Also, you test with the regex `-match` operator a string `'@students.test.com'`, but in regex, the dot has special meaning (Any Character), so you need to escape these dots with a backslash.

This should work for you:

```
# Get a string array of users to be deleted from the database
$NotEnroled = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "my-server" -Database "my-db" -Query "select UserName from StudentsToDeleteFromO365"

# Get a string array of UserPrincipalNames.
# Because of using the regex '-match' operator, you need to escape the dots in the string.
# The '$' anchors the regex to match from the end of the string.
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | 
             Where-Object {($_.UserPrincipalName -match '@students\.test\.com$') -and 
                          (($null -ne $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress) -or ($null -ne $_.ForwardingAddress))} | 
             Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName

# Next find the items in the $Mailboxes array that exist in $NotEnrolled
$UsersToDelete = @($Mailboxes | Where-Object { $NotEnroled -contains $_ })
```

The variable `$UsersToDelete` now has all the UPNs from the `$Mailboxes` array that are also found in the `$NotEnroled` array.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work and i'm unsure why. I compared the lists in excel by using vlookup and i know there are email addresses which appear in both lists. But $UsersToDelete is showing nothing at all. Any idea why? Data format different or spaces in both lists or something?

Comment: @FuxMolder I cannot see what is returned from the database of course. Can you check the contents of the `$Mailboxes` array and does that compare with what we expect?

Comment: @FuxMolder Instead of `($_.UserPrincipalName -match '@students\.test\.com$')` here you can also do `($_.UserPrincipalName -like '*@students.test.com')`. In that case you use the wildcard character * and because `-like` does not use regex matching, there is no need to escape the dots in the string.

Comment: @FuxMolder What exactly is in `$NotEnroled` as returned from the database? From your description it is simply an array of strings with UPN's in it.

Comment: Hi. $NotEnroled and $MailBoxes contain a list of student email address which is their UPN. I checked and both lists have data. Example of the data is like 1234567@students.test.com. Running `$UsersToDelete = @($Mailboxes | Where-Object { $NotEnroled -contains $_ })` doesn't assign anything to $UsersToDelete so my guess is there is something different what can't be seen between the list $NotEnroled from DB and list $Mailboxes from o365 exchange.

Comment: I tried to trim spaces in the sql by $NotEnroled = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "my-server" -Database "my-db" -Query "select rtrim(ltrim(UserName)) from StudentsToDeleteFromO365" but this didn't help. $UsersToDelete is still empty. I tried to assign the list of couple UPNs to both variables by running $NotEnroled = '1234567@students.test.com'  $Mailboxes = '1234567@students.test.com'. When i do that the '$UsersToDelete = @($Mailboxes | Where-Object { $NotEnroled -contains $_ })' works fine.

Comment: @FuxMolder Hmmmmmm. That sounds like the `$NotEnroled` does contain something else than just plain strings. Can you do a `$NotEnroled[0].GetType().FullName` and check if it returns `System.String`? Also do a `$NotEnroled.GetType().FullName` to see if it is `System.Object[]` or something else like a DataTable perhaps.